# present participle or reduced relative clause?

Tags: sentence-meaning, relative-clauses, present-participles

> in the midst of desperation spread by the darkness fraught with fear,
>   ***there appeared oriflammes of knights***, ***waving against the harsh and merciless storms***

The expression in bold refers to ***knights*** or  ***there appeared oriflammes of knights***  or ***oriflammes of knights*** ?

I mean, in this sentence and context ,

1.)is the action of waving related to knights as in "knights who wave against the hursh and merciless stroms" which is meaningless to me  ?

or

2.) related to the oriflammes of knights as in oriflammes which is waving?

or

3.)is the mentioned expression in bold present participle which explains whole sentence it follows,  meaning that oriflammes of knights appeared while waving. ?

Comment: This appears to have a number of typos (*hursh* and *stroms*?).  Could you please check to see if you've copied it correctly, and could you please tell us what it's from?

Comment: I've tried to write it by myself. I edited the mistakes by the way.

Comment: Oh, I see!  Thanks for letting us know :-)  It helps if we know whether we're helping someone interpret a sentence written by someone else or work on one of their own.

Answer (score 1):

What appeared is

> oriflammes of knights

The word *waving* **can** modify either  *oriflammes* or *knights*. And I can speculate as to which one it modifies (probably *oriflammes*), perhaps further context can make it clearer.

Both *knights* and *oriflammes* can wave.

One thing problematic could be *waving **against** the wind*. Things usually *wave **in** the wind*, which is why I would ask for more context. Perhaps it is just an unfortunate choice of prepositions.

Comment: Meanwhile ,it is me who completely wrote it :) , I want you to notice that I did not use the word "wind" , but "storm" ."Against the storm" must be changed to "in the storm" do you think?

Comment: Secondly , what I still don't get is that why "waving against the harsh and merciless storms" can not be used as present participle?.In Oxford Guide to English Grammer book, it says                                                "A clause with an active participle (e.g. playing, serving) means an action at the
same time as the action of the main clause.Mike hurt his hand playing badminton.
We were rushing about serving tea to everyone.
Am I not able to use "waving..." in the role that "playing and serving " take in the sentences above? @pazzo

Comment: Sorry, there have been actual winds and storms outside my house this morning. Let me switch to a different device and update my answer.

Comment: stay safe and sound :) while it occured to my mind, I better write it in case I may forget later . What if we put  "waving against the hursh and merciless storms"  at the beginning of the sentence? Therefore  may it mean that the expression starting with "waving..." takes  the role of present participle do you think? @pazzo